# Portion of Screen freezes on opening Transmission [Lubuntu]

Tags: lubuntu, screen

Whenever I open Transmission (torrent), the top left corner of my screen  freezes and covers everything. Closing Transmission, unfreezes it. It also sometimes happens when I open a .pdf

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me from time to time.  sometimes sublime gets down right unusable.  It seems the issue is a GPU crash of some kind.  Every place I have found so far gives the same advice, reboot, update your video drivers, buy a linux approved video card.   Pretty hard on a laptop.  Whenever its gets bad, I just kick the machine and it works fine for another couple of weeks.